# Unable to route without # in an AngularJS website

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, url-rewriting

My `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thesite\.com\.cp\-45\.webhostbox\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thesite\.com\.cp\-45\.webhostbox\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.thesite\.com\/" [R=301,L]
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

My base URL is set to root in `index.html`:

```
<base href="/">
```

And I also have the following line of code in my AngularJS app configuration:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Despite all this, I am unable to get rid of a 404 when I try to directly access any page on my site without the # symbol in the URL. I can follow the links alright but once on a page, refreshing it returns a 404. Is there something I am missing in my rewrites?

Just in case it helps, my Angular app config looks like this (partial code below):

```
// create the module and name it asApp
var asApp = angular.module('asApp', ['ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
asApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    // route for the home page
    .when('/', {
        title: 'Learn Spanish with thesite | Unconventional tricks for the crazy learner',
        templateUrl : 'pages/thesitehome.html?v=1.1',
        controller  : 'mainController'
    })

    // route for the about page
    .when('/about', {
        title: 'About thesite and its penchant for cunning Spanish learning tricks',
        templateUrl : 'pages/aboutus.html?v=2',
        controller  : 'mainController'
    })

    // route for dictionary term
    .when('/dictionary/:word2lookup', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/dictionary.html?v=1',
        controller  : 'dictController'
    })

    // route for dictionary
    .when('/dictionary', {
        title: 'The thesite dictionary – Look up Spanish or English words in a jiffy',
        templateUrl : 'pages/dictionary.html?v=1',
        controller  : 'mainController'
    })

    // route for the 404 page not found error
    .when('/notfound', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/404.html',
        controller  : 'mainController'
    })

    // route otherwise
    .otherwise({
        controller: 'mainController',
        templateUrl: 'pages/404.html'
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Any nudge in the right direction will be highly appreciated! Oh and the website in question is live just in case you wish to take a look and see the problem first-hand.

Answer (score 0):

Try following tuts.

https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <base href="/">
</head>
```